# Samba write access for removable media (Model B)

Tags: samba

I've recently revived my Raspberry Pi B, which is not nearly as powerful as the 3's that are out now. I've resorted to using it as a media hub for all of my hard drives and large flash drives as network shares. Because neither my desktop nor my surface have disk drives or floppy drives, I have attached a floppy drive via USB and plan to do the same with my USB CD drive as soon as it arrives however I have already had a problem with the floppy drive as I can read files but I can't write to them. Here are my following configurations for the fstab and samba configuration files:

Samba:

**Output omitted**

[FLDRIVE]
        writeable = yes
        path = /media/fldrive

Fstab:

/dev/sdb1 /media/fldrive vfat defaults 0 0

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit: Yes, the floppy disk is set to read/write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try `force user`

Someone in an [archived Red Hat mailing list](https://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-install-list/2003-July/msg00064.html) was having the same issue:

> While I am able to share /mnt/floppy, and it appears to work for read
>   access, I am unable to give write permissions to /dev/fd0 (mounted as
>   /mnt/floppy) to any Samba users.

The solution was the `force user` option in `samba.conf`:

> On 1 Jul 2003 at 22:00, Steeve McCauley wrote:
>
> > You'll want to play with the
> >
> > force user
> >
> > force group
> >
> > force create mode
> >
> > force directory mode
> >
> > options in smb.conf.  "man 5 smb.conf" for details.
>
> Thanks Steeve, force user did the trick.  I should have tried that  myself, but for some obscure reason I was concentrating on playing 
>   around with the permissions of /mnt/floppy, mount and fstab.
>
> For the record, the shard of smb.conf follows:

```
# Floppy_drive [floppy]
comment = floppy
path = /mnt/floppy
read only = no
public = yes
force user = root
```

> Russell